# Does this authentication scheme exist?

Tags: authentication, public-key-infrastructure, custom-scheme

For an IoT project I've defined a simple security schema. Does this already exsist and if so, how is it called?

Definition:

> 1. There is one root key.
> 2. With every key, a child key can be generated. The creation key becomes the parent.
> 3. A child key can have write, read, delete, and/or execution rights.
> 4. A parent has access to a child, a childs child, etcetera.
> 5. A child has no access to a parent.
> 6. A child can have an expiration timestamp which, when expired, keeps all children intact.
> 7. A child can inherit the experation timestamp from parent.

This creates a tree of keys which can be given to people, devices, apps etcetera. The amount of keys created does not matter, a device can also have multiple keys.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be partially describing a PKI, and partially describing an authorisation schema.

While I realise this doesn't answer your question, you might want to split these concerns:

- describe an authorisation scheme based on the relationships you describe, and the rights they grant (I am fairly sure I have seen the sort of scheme you describe before, but can't think of a name for it)
- and describe the authentication scheme you mention, based on keys, as well as the mechanisms for key issuance, etc.

You may find it useful to do a more formal [requirement analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_analysis) to work out whether your approach works for your actual use cases.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand you correctly. First a more abstract form and secondly a practical one?